# Using IPC::Run with timeouts results in Modification of a read-only value error

Tags: perl

I'm using `IPC::Run`  with timeouts and I am getting an odd error:
`Modification of a read-only value attempted at ${HOME}/perl5/lib/perl5/IPC/Run.pm line 1693`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Run qw(timeout);
​
my $job_command = '/bin/ls';
my $timeout_value = 20;
my $t = timeout($timeout_value);
IPC::Run::run($job_command, undef, undef, undef, $t);
```

Anyone have experience w/ this?

Edited to add that this is the results w/ perl v5.16.3 and v5.22.0 w/ IPC::Run version 20200505.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`undef` is not a valid argument.

Simply use

```perl
IPC::Run::run($job_command, $t);
```

Test:

```perl
use IPC::Run qw( run timeout );

run([ 'perl', '-e', 'sleep' ], timeout(5));
```

Output:

```
IPC::Run: timeout on timer #1 at /home/ikegami/usr/perlbrew/perls/5.32.0t/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/IPC/Run.pm line 2951.
```